# How Spring data jpa register the entities into hibernate without specifying into any configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am just a new learner of Hibernate core, When we are only using hibernate without spring or other frameworks, we have to register an entity to Hibernate configuration and one way of this registration is using **Configuration** class like this:

```
if (sessionFactory == null){
   Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
   configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
   configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Product.class);
   sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

As I know hibernate does not have auto scan packages, so I just want to know how Spring data jpa register the entities that scanned, I made some search and found that spring does not use this way to register entities into hibernate.

How exectly Hibernate interact with entities without specify them in hibernate.cfg.xml and without add them one by one into hibernate using addAnnotatedClass in Configuration class?

Comment: It's pretty easy for Spring to get all the `@Entity` annotated classes. The XML config is a thing of the past.

Comment: @Kayaman this is not my quastion, hibernate does have auto config, spring data jpa does, how spring data jpa register entities into hibernate ?

Comment: If you want to find out the details, go read the source. Shouldn't be too hard to find the relevant classes.

Comment: This is JPA interfaces, not native Hibernate. In JPA, the container, Spring, is responsible for loading persistence.xml, so it just uses its own configuration and package scanning to build that instead of an xml to pass to JPA/Hibernate. If you want to learn about the config involved - docs will help, but best option is to try a provider that isn't automatically plumbed in so you have to write some of it yourself. It easier to see when you have to write the plumbing code to tie in to a new provider yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not done by spring-data but done by core spring. Codewise , it is about configuring a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` especially the property [packageToScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan(java.lang.String...)) which will finally call the following [JPA API](https://javadoc.io/static/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html#createContainerEntityManagerFactory(jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo,java.util.Map)) to create an `EntityManagerFactory`:

```java
EntityManagerFactory emf = persistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitInfo,propertiesMap)
```

The `PersistenceUnitInfo` here has a method (i.e [getManagedClassNames()](https://javadoc.io/static/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html#getManagedClassNames())) to define the class names of all the entities.

Spring implements `PersistenceUnitInfo` which is called `SpringPersistenceUnitInfo`. `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` will somehow scan all the classes that are annotated with `@Entity` , `@Embeddable` , `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Converter` under the packages defined by `packageToScan` (see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/293e6ddf85c21094aac919a832aebb3757bb3e06/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/PersistenceManagedTypesScanner.java#L96C63-L97C1)) to configure `SpringPersistenceUnitInfo` and finally passed to the above mentioned JPA API to bootstrap the `EntityManagerFactory`